# Running IE as different users with Protractor

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor, e2e-testing, user-roles, ui-testing

The application I am testing appears (hides and displays menu options) differently for the users with different Active Directory roles assigned to them.

So this is what I am trying to automate,

1. Launch IE as a user 1  - let's call it browser 1 (can be manually done by shift + right click on IE and choose "Run as a different user" and supply the user name and password for user 1).
2. Open the application in browser 1.
3. Perform some operations in browser 1.
4. Launch IE as user 2 - let's call it browser 2.
5. Open the application again in browser 2.
6. Verify what I should and should not be seeing in browser 2 as user 2.

I have done something similar for a windows application in the past using PSExec and Test.Stack.White.

I don't know if this is possible to do it in protractor. If it is can some one point me in the right direction ?

Thanks all for your time and help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I think Protractor not support for multi-thread.